# Is there a way to communicate between javascript and python?

Tags: javascript, python, communication

What i mean by communication between javascript and python is, that I take input in javascript (through an html page input) , then send that data to a python file , python does the work on the data and then give output , and javascript read that data back from python and show output in html page.
[chart of the process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAc1E.jpg)
I tried to make this lil chart to show what i mean.

to be precise what I wanna do is, take input as math functions in js, make meshgrid and do other calculation in python, send the final arrays to js to plot it there.

Comment: You can try with ajax  request

Comment: A typical solution would be to run the Python function as a web application. One of the suitable web frameworks for this would be Flask. Then you make an HTTP call to the web application.